# redirecting directories with a few exceptions using .htaccess and mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm using mod_rewrite in a ManagedFusion settings file (similar to .htaccess) and I want to forward all incoming requests to another port on the server, except for a few folders.

So far I have this (with the folder ui, forms, clientsystem and widgets being ignored)

```
RewriteEngine On  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !ui$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !forms$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !clientsystem$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !widgets$
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8050/$1 [P,L]
```

This works fine as long as those exception directories don't exist, however when they are created, the rewriteengine will simply trigger again and in that case it will match the rule, thereby forwarding me to the other port after all.

How could I solve this?

Another question, if I want queries like '?file=bla' to be forwarded as well, will this simply work like this?

Edit: this is what I ended up with:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^ui
RewriteCond $1 !^forms
RewriteCond $1 !^clientsystem
RewriteCond $1 !^widgets
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://localhost:8050/$1?%1 [P,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond $1 !^ui
RewriteCond $1 !^forms
RewriteCond $1 !^clientsystem
RewriteCond $1 !^widgets
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://localhost:8050/$1 [P,R]
```

Some redundancy but it works.

Comment: Remark on your regexp in rewriterule: I don't think you need that first / after ^. If you want to be sure, append ? after / so it always matches, with or without / as a first char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for second part of your question, make RewriteRule flags to be like: `[P,L,QSA]`. QSA stands for Query String Append, and will do the obvious to your final string before redirection occurs.

By the way, you would most likely want to include R in flags, since it will truly redirect client to new URL.

Update: so now I understand that you want to skip those directories in any case?

If that's so, then you could use

```
RewriteCond $1 !^ui
RewriteCond $1 !^forms
...
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://localhost:8050/$1 [P,L,QSA]
```

which would simply not match and not forward user in case requested URL starts with any of given strings.

Comment: Thanks, yes you're right I don't want to forward in any case. His solution also seemed to work though, I'll try yours as well.

Comment: I tried the QSA flag but I'm not sure if it works. Is there a way to test this easily? I went to http://localhost:8040/test/?tempquery and I turned logging on with RewriteLog "rewrite.log" and RewriteLogLevel 9, in the log file it says: 2010-06-02T14:41:58 [Rewrite] Proxy: http://localhost:8050/test/
Is that expected?

Comment: You should see your full URL, along with query string part in your logs on line such as 127.0.0.1 - - [02/Jun/2010:15:13:58 +0200] [localhost/sid#.../initial] (1) [perdir C:/www/root/] redirect to http://localhost/index.php?asdf [REDIRECT/302]. Honestly, I'm not sure how mod_rewrite handles internal redirect to another host. So, in my experience, I would have used R,QSA flags there and would have no problem with it.

Comment: One more thing to note. QSA is not needed in normal operation. QSA is needed if you were redirecting url something?foo=bar to index.php?action=something and would like to append any remaining query string to the end, so that final url looks like index.php?action=something&foo=bar. In normal operation, apache passes whatever query string was prior to rewrite, to final url. If you want to prevent this behavior, append ? to the final url in your RewriteRule.

Comment: I decided to skip the QSA thing as it did not work for me, see my edited post for what I ended up with. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to only apply the rule if the file or directory by that name doesn't exist:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Btw, I find this mod_rewrite cheat sheet pretty handy:  http://dreev.es/modrewrite.