# Need to restrict url rewrite for a single folder

Tags: php, zend-framework, .htaccess, url-rewriting

Hi guys I have the following htaccess file set up in order to allow url rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
#RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule .* index.php
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|swf|css|htm|html|php5)$ index.php 

php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
AddType text/css .css
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

I want to create an iframe which points to a file in a folder on the public_html folder however according to the htaccess set above I need to set up an exception for this one folder and its contents - how do I do that?

EDIT====================

My folder stucture is set up as below which is the standard for zend framework based applications:

```
application
html
->importer
library
```

I want any reference to www.mysite.com/importer refer to it as normal instead of considering importer as a parameter to be passed to an index.php file.

Comment: If you ONLY want it to process when accessing files within a specific folder, just put the `.htaccess` file in that folder.

Comment: Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2957468/redirecting-directories-with-a-few-exceptions-using-htaccess-and-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restrict url rewriting to a specific folder, just put in this folder the **.htaccess** file with the rules you want to apply.